# Разделить ввод данных и результат работы на 2 кейса в switch | Ошибка Exception in thread "main"

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test_switch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int choice;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {

        // Creating menu
        System.out.println("Press 1 for entry string");
        System.out.println("Press 2 for check results");
        System.out.println("Press 3 to Quit \n ");
        System.out.println("Make your choice ");
        choice = scanner.nextInt();
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            String str1 = "";
            try (Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in)) {
                str1 = sc1.nextLine();
            }
            String codeString = "";
            String formattedString = "";
            for (char ch : str1.toCharArray()) {
                codeString += Character.isAlphabetic(ch) ? String.format("%-3s", ch - 'a' + 1) : ch;
                formattedString += Character.isAlphabetic(ch) ? String.format("%-3s", ch) : ch;
            }
            System.out.println(formattedString);
            System.out.println(codeString);
            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("results");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.exit(0);

        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid choice! Please make a valid choice.\n");
            break;

        }
    }
}
}
```

Данный код заменяет каждую букву её номером в алфавите(латиница).
А сам результат выглядит следующим образом: в одной строке текст с двумя пробелами между буквами, в следующей строке под каждой буквой её номер.
Вот так это выглядит:

```
h  e  l  l  o   w  o  r  l  d  
8  5  12 12 15  23 15 18 12 4
```

Но я не понимаю как разделить код, что бы он соответствовал меню пользователя.
В первом кейсе был бы только ввод, а во втором только результат.
Возможно нужно сделать отдельные функции для этого?

upd:

Перенёс

```
System.out.println(formattedString); 
System.out.println(codeString);
```

в case 2.

А `String codeString = ""; String formattedString = "";` за while

После появления меню нажимаю 1, ввожу нужный мне текст и получаю сообщение об ошибке.
Вот так выглядит консоль целиком:

```
Press 1 for entry string
Press 2 for check results
Press 3 to Quit 
 
Make your choice 
1//ввожу 
hello world//ввожу
Press 1 for entry string//далее программа выдаёт ошибку
Press 2 for check results
Press 3 to Quit 
 
Make your choice 
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

Мне кажется проблема в том, что номера букв,
как у hello world (8  5  12 12 15  23 15 18 12 4  )
передаются в switch, но могу ошибаться

Comment: непонятна часть "чтобы соответствовал меню пользователя"? Какому меню? Где оно? Как должен выглядет в итоге результат?

Comment: Перенесите System.out.println(formattedString);
            System.out.println(codeString); в case 2:  Ну и String codeString = "";
            String formattedString = ""; за while

Comment: @Эникейщик, меню написано в коде, не подумал, что нужно бы и конечный результат с меню привести

Comment: @Виктор, исправил, но теперь возникает проблема Exception in thread "main", наверное потому что номера букв считаются как значения для кейса?

Comment: @Kajletskiy обновите вопрос с новыми данными, которые у Вас получились

Comment: Смотрите ответ, если пойдёт - помечайте как принятый ответ и закроем вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int choice;
    String codeString = "";
    String formattedString = "";

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {

    // Creating menu
    System.out.println("Press 1 for entry string");
    System.out.println("Press 2 for check results");
    System.out.println("Press 3 to Quit \n ");
    System.out.println("Make your choice ");

    choice = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();

    switch (choice) {
    case 1:
        String str1 = scanner.nextLine();

        codeString = "";
        formattedString = "";
        for (char ch : str1.toCharArray()) {
            codeString += Character.isAlphabetic(ch) ? String.format("%-3s", ch - 'a' + 1) : ch;
            formattedString += Character.isAlphabetic(ch) ? String.format("%-3s", ch) : ch;
        }
        break;

    case 2:
        System.out.println(formattedString);
        System.out.println(codeString);
        break;
    case 3:
        System.exit(0);

    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid choice! Please make a valid choice.\n");
        break;    
    }
    } // while
} // main
```

Вывод:

```
Press 1 for entry string
Press 2 for check results
Press 3 to Quit

Make your choice
1
qwe rty
Press 1 for entry string
Press 2 for check results
Press 3 to Quit

Make your choice
2
q  w  e   r  t  y
17 23 5   18 20 25
Press 1 for entry string
Press 2 for check results
Press 3 to Quit

Make your choice
```